# DQL script for using order by clause to get case insensitive values

Tags: dql

How to write a DQL script for getting the case insensitive string values using order by.
 select *from country order by lower(name) giving me error. Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: You should provide more details about the input data and the current code you have tried.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.Example:  apple,Apple, ball etc..By using DQL, I would like to retrieve in the order apple,Apple,ball etc. But when  I am using "select name from names(table_name) order by name asc"; I am getting all the names starting with capital letter upto Z and then all the names starting with small letters. Is there a  way , I can retrieve the names with case insensitive pa.ttern using DQL order by clause.

Comment: Do it on the question. I'm not a DQL specialist. Just trying to improve your question so others can provide a proper answer. Have a good day.